# How to send hidden field value to db on webform submit

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using Drupal 7 webform api, have a created a field in my `_form_alter` hook in a custom module, but while on page load the hidden field contains the correct value, when I submit the form it does not save to the mysql table, and gives me an empty cell

```
$form['State'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => 'Unread',
  '#attributes' => array('id' => array('stateform')),    
);
```

How can I make it save to the mysql table on submit?

UPDATE:

```
$form['State'] = array(
'#type' => 'hidden',
'#title' => t('Hidden'),    
'#attributes' => array('id' => array('state')),
);
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','mymodule') . '/js/custom.js');
```

Comment: What code is in your submit function?

Comment: I do not have one, since am using webform's default submit function.

Answer (score 1):

You also will need to write a [hook_form_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/7/search/hook_form_submit) for your form. In the _form_submit() you will take the hidden value and store it where you like.

That is the simple answer for your question. If you provide more details there could be other ways of handling the data. What is your form action?

Comment: The hidden value should be configured to be "less secure" while creating the webform component.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any hooks to do this. You can simply create an element via the webform UI of type "hidden." and it will save when the webform is submitted.

Comment: From my updated post above, am now using a JS instead of `#value` to fill in the value in my hidden field. Again it is found in the _alter hook, but the above mentioned methods did not work for me. Unless am doing it all wrong here.

I am using webform's default submit actions here, which send the data to the `webform_submitted_data` table.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Allows you to get rid of all php code except for the 1 line that adds js. Which type of hidden field did you add? Don't use the "secure value" type as that is not alterable via js.

Answer (score 0):

This value should be stored in

$form_state['values']

You can access that in your hook_form_submit.   It wouldn't hurt to do a drupal_set_message on $form_state['values'], so that you can see exactly what values are stored there.